# connects to server but database is not created and not saving chat history. i am using nodejs, mongodb to save and robomongo to view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, robo3t

i developed  a client side application and have two html files 
   This is index.html and after filling form redirect to chat.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <title>Join | chatApp</title>
           <meta name = "viewport" content ="width=deveice-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable =no ">
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
       </head>
        <body class ="centered-form">
            <div class ="centered-form__form">

                <form action="/chat.html">

                     <div class="form-field">
                         <h3>want to Join a Chat</h3>
                     </div>
                     <div class="form-field">
                      <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" autofocus/>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-field">
                    <label>Room Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="room"/>
                    </div>
                     <div class="form-field"></div>
                       <button>Join</button>
                </form>

            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

This is the chat.html and wants to save all the chat history in a database.

```
 <body class="chat"> 
        <div class="chat__sidebar">
            <h3>people</h3>
            <div id="users">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="chat__main">
             <ol id="messages" class="chat__messages"></ol>
        <div class="chat__footer">
          <form id="message-form" method ="post" action="/add">
               <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="message" autofocus autocomplete ="off"/>
               <button>send</button>
          </form>
        <button id="send-location">send location</button>

           </div>
        </div>


        <script id="message-template" type="text/template">
         <li class="message"> 
          <div class="message__title">
             <h4>{{from}}</h4>
             <span>{{createdAt}}</span>
          </div>
         <div class="message__body">
             <p>{{text}}</p>
         </div>
        </li>
        </script>    


        <script id="location-message-template" type="text/template">
         <li class="message"> 
          <div class="message__title">
             <h4>{{from}}</h4>
             <span>{{createdAt}}</span>
          </div>
         <div class="message__body">
         <p> <a href="{{url}}" target="_blank">My current location</a> </p>
         </div>
        </li>
        </script>
    </body>
```

code to save in a database

```
var express = require("express");

 var app = express();

 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


 var mongoose =require('mongoose');
 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chatApp');


var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

     message:{type: String}
 });

 var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);


app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
   res.sendFile(__dirname, '/public/chat.html');

 });

app.post('/add', function (req, res){


    var message = req.body.message;


  var myData = new User();

   myData.message = message;

  myData.save().then((item)=>{
    res.send('item saved');
  },(err)=>{
    res.status(400).send('unable to save');
  });
});
```

Comment: You getting any error while saving in db. Please print error also there.